# Parse errors when code written in xcode 4.5 run in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone application development. I have written a code in xcode 4.5 and the code is working fine there. I copied that code and pasted it in xcode 4.2, cleaned it and when i build it i get lots of parse errors. Some of the errors are; missing @end, illegal interface qualifier,expected an objective-c directive,expected identifier or '(' etc.And most of these errors are in AppDelegate.m file. I am totally clueless what to do. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to get much help unless you show some code that's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Open your AppDelegate.m file, and scroll down at the end of file simply write `@end` at the last line.